# Proper way of creating feature space for Machine learning algorithms

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

This question is maybe general. Can a feature space consisting of negative feature values be used train a machine learning algorithm i.e., Logistic regression?

```
feature,feature,feature,class-label  
-0.5,0.2,1,yes         
0.9,-0.7,2,no   
 ..........     
...........
```

Comment: You'd better normalize it first.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28statistics%29

Answer (score 2):

Feature space has to be consistent with given model. Most of the machine learning classifiers (including Logistic regression) require features to be:

- real numbers (sign does not matter)
- constant length

and that's all.